# How to tell if LPCWSTR text is numeric?

Tags: c++

Entire string needs to be made of integers which as we know are 0123456789 I am trying with following function but it doesnt seem to work

```
bool isNumeric( const char* pszInput, int nNumberBase )
{
    string base = "0123456789";
    string input = pszInput;

    return (::strspn(input.substr(0, nNumberBase).c_str(), base.c_str()) == input.length());

}
```

and the example of using it in code...

```
isdigit = (isNumeric((char*)text, 11));
```

It returns true even with text in the string

Comment: What is `test` and why are you casting it to `char*`?

Comment: You can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to check that.

Comment: `nNumberBase` is a rather misleading name. It doesn't look to me as though you are using base 11 numbers.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks! This led me to solution

Comment: I rolled back the edit. If you want to answer your own question, you can do so.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the issue is that `text` is actually `LPCWSTR` which is `const wchar_t*`. We have to infer this fact from the question title and the cast that you made.

Now, that cast is a problem. The compiler objected to you passing `text`. It said that `text` is not `const char*`. By casting you have not changed what `text` is, you simply lied to the compiler. And the compiler took its revenge.

What happens next is that you reinterpret the wide char buffer as being a narrow 8 bit buffer. If your wide char buffer has latin text, encoded as UTF-16, then every other byte will be zero. Hence the reinterpret cast that you do results in `isNumeric` thinking that the string is only 1 character long.

What you need to do is either:

1. Start using UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` buffers in `isNumeric`.
2. Convert from UTF-16 to ANSI before calling `isNumeric`.

You should think about this carefully. It seems that at present you have a rather unholy mix of ANSI and UTF-16 in your program. You really ought to settle on a standard character encoding an use it consistently throughout. That is tenable internal to your program, but you will encounter external text that could use different encodings. Deal with that by converting at the boundary between your program and the outside world.

Personally I don't understand why you are using C strings at all. Surely you should be using `std::wstring` or `std::string`.

Comment: My head hurts from your answer but its good to understand what happens. After thinking the best thing for my project would be 2.Convert from UTF-16 to ANSI before calling isNumeric. Can you write how would you do this in code?